# VSTS builds - how to define new variable in custom build step and pass to next build steps

Tags: azure-devops

We are using VSTS to build our VS solution.

Is there a way to define custom Build Step, for example a PowerShell script, that creates a new variable to be passed to further build steps?

There's nothing about it in MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Task Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to do this.

> To invoke a logging command, simply emit the command via standard
>   output. For example, from a PowerShell task:
>
> "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot, Eddie. Looks like a good theft from TeamCity: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCDL/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity   "Good Artists Copy; Great Artists Steal" :)

Comment: How do you do this on a Mac which doesn't have PowerShell?

Comment: Michael - You just need to write to stdout using echo from Mac bash script.  Make sure you surround the command in quotes like this echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=xcode.buildNumber;]'$buildNumber

Answer (score 1):

For Mac, do this :

```
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=variableName;]'$variableValue
```